# Threaded port scanner not outputting anything

Tags: python, networking, python-multithreading

I am attempting to create a threaded port scanner and for some reason the following code causes the program to wait and then stop with no output. I have tested the target with nmap and port 80 is open so I am pretty sure it is the program and not the target.

```
import socket
import threading
import concurrent.futures

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.settimeout(2)

def scan(target, port):
    try:
        con = s.connect((target, port))
        print(f"Port {port} is open")
        con.close()
    except:
        pass

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
    for port in range(1, 100):
        executor.submit(scan, "hackthissite.org", port)
```

Comment: As you are ignoring the exceptions you aren't seeing what they are. Don't do that. You can't connect the same TCP socket to multiple targets. You need a new socket per connection, and you need to close it on both success and failure.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I printed the exception and it says: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied 

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Have you considered fixing the bug in your code I mentioned?

Comment: Yes, I added the con.close() as part of the exception as well. I am pretty sure that is what you meant when you said that the same TCP cannot connect to multiple targets. After messing with that for a while I was still unable to get rid of the Invalid argument exception.

Comment: I can only suggest that you read I wrote again. You've missed it completely.

Comment: Doesn't closing the socket allow for a new connection?

Comment: Sorry I am new to using sockets and I am not familiar with some concepts.

Comment: You need a new socket per connection. I already said that.

Comment: I am asking if closing the socket allows for a new connection to be made. As I said I am new to this concept so any code examples are greatly appreciated.

Comment: And I am now telling you, for the third time, that you need a new socket per connection. How many times is it going to take for this to finally sink in? and what happened when you tried it?